# Filter an array of objects with jquery grep but the criteria is a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I'm trying to filter down an array of objects.  But the property of the object to filter on is defined elsewhere as a variable and not 100% how i can construct the dot-notation syntax.

So i have a array object like this

```
var listings = [
    {"id" : "1", "name":"a name", "surname" : "a surname"},
    {"id" : "2", "name":"b name", "surname" : "b surname"},
    {"id" : "3", "name":"c name", "surname" : "c surname"}
]
```

I have a variable the specifies what property of the object to filter on. This variable isn't always set to name. In the example above it could be on id,name or surname.

```
var filter = 'id'
```

A var for the filter val to look for

```
var filterVal = '2'
```

Then i have this grep call.

```
listings = $.grep(listings, function (obj, index) {
return  obj.id === filterVal;
});
```

But instead of having obj.id hard coded I want something like:

```
obj."value of filter variable" === filterVal
```

Thanks in advance

Ben

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make use of square bracket notation instead of dot notation.

```
var idKey = "name";
$.grep(listings, function (obj) {
    return obj[idKey] === filterVal;
});
```